# xampp + PHPMailer + Gmail = SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have installed PHPMailer using Composer and added all the Composer dependency to use Google XOAuth2 authentication.
Then I have followed some tutorials to get the refresh token with the Gmail API.
Everything should be working just fine. I did all the paper work right. Right?!
Despite my best intention and all the docs, I'm not able to establish a SMTP connection to smtp.gmail.com
I get this error:

```
2017-10-20 18:01:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c17sm2715728wrg.26 - gsmtp
2017-10-20 18:01:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-10-20 18:01:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [151.61.40.58]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-10-20 18:01:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-10-20 18:01:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-10-20 18:01:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-10-20 18:01:45
2017-10-20 18:01:45
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

My code is straight from the PHPMailer Gmail XOAUTH example.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

require 'lib/php/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

$email = 'seckrit-stuff';
$clientId = 'seckrit-stuff';
$clientSecret = 'seckrit-stuff';
$refreshToken = 'seckrit-stuff';

$provider = new Google(
    [
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    ]
);
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth(
        [
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'userName' => $email,
        ]
    )
);

$mail->setFrom($email, 'Matteo Bini');
$mail->addAddress('seckrit-stuff', 'Matteo Bini');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail XOAUTH2 SMTP test';
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->msgHTML('<strong>HTML</strong> message!');
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';


if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Could you please help me finding a way to use PHPMailer with Gmail in localhost (xampp)?

Comment: Try checking "Allow less secure apps: OFF" Settings in your Google Account. You may have to turn it on in order to use your GMail with PHP code. This is because a normal web-app is considered as less secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with OAuth. You’ve got a much earlier issue at the TLS level. Either you’re missing the openssl extension, it’s misconfigured, or your CA certificates are out of date.

This issue is covered in the troubleshooting guide the error links to - check using openssl.

Comment: I have read the troubleshooting guide before posting the question and I have enabled the openssl extension on xampp php.ini file as well.
Using the troubleshooting guide tip I tested the extension with echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n";
It says SSL loaded.
Should have I done something more or differently?

Comment: Well that’s good, but try the openssl command line examples in the guide. Also try SMTPDebug =3.

Comment: I solved my issue. Thank you!
I used SMTPDebug=3, I found out what the error was and added this line of code to php.ini openssl.cafile=C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem. Obviously after having downloaded cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: That's good, so it was that your CA certs were out of date. Please mark this answer as correct if it's helped you.